Why does it take me so long to solve relatively easy problems and what can I do about it?
I know that some people just take longer to wrap their head around some things, but I must say that this is quite annoying.
I am currently a freshman math student and have encountered the following problem during my self-study time (topic: subspaces/vector spaces):
"Show that the union of subspaces A, B, C is a subspace of V if and only if one of the three contains the other two."
I managed to solve the question, but only after tedious effort, roughly 45 min of concentrated thinking (to be honest the author stated that it would be considerably more difficult than the problem before). Yet I find it pretty frustrating because the solution is fairly easy. I observed that this happens to me quite often with other problems of similar difficulty and when I see some of my peers just recognizing the solution near instantly I'm starting to think I'm doing something wrong here.
Another issue I'm having (again, with problems of similar difficulty - important to note) is that I very often have the right idea of which direction to go down, but way too many times it takes a lot of effort to actually do the mental steps. Often I feel like I have overlooked something at some point, need to retrace all the steps I've taken so far, etc... could it be that my working memory/processing speed has hit its limit here? Seriously - is my intelligence just not high enough? Realistic advice only please; I don't need anybody to tell me that I can achieve anything with hard work.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

This site is slowly evolving into r/Math

Have you considered that it might be a question of practice? I've spent ages on math puzzles that someone with more practice just laughed about while we where at the same level for other types of math.

You're problem may simply be related to proof techniques, and , in first place, with the logical analysis of the goal you have to reach . A well known reference for this : How to prove it by Velleman.

@TrystwithFreedom So true!! I actually wouldn't mind a hybrid of r/math and math stackexchange!

This comic addresses this issue: https://abstrusegoose.com/230

If, after solving a problem, you understand it well enough that you now also see a faster way to the same solution, that means you did well; means you didn't just formulaically-plod to the answer, write it down and move on to the next; nor did you just apply some rules of thumb to come to a fast answer, without understanding the concepts behind those rules of thumb. Instead you understand what the result you found, means. That's a really good thing. Don't underestimate the value and importance of that feeling.

I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a really faulty premise. Ability to solve problems faster is very much dependent on hard work. If you haven't spent 1000 hours on solving problems, then you don't even have the bare minimum that the average person needs to go beyond a beginner level of skill at solving problems. Time and effort are not sufficient, but are necessary. Almost everyone who can solve problems fast HAVE had 1000 hours of practice at some kind of problem-solving.

@user21820: I disagree. You can work for hours with bad methods and not get any progress. Expertise is time + proper feedback.

@Taladris: Clearly, you didn't read my comment carefully. Read the second-last sentence.

Trust me, I think everyone feels this way. Try to enjoy the process and take frequent breaks.

Thinking that hard things should have been easy after you've successfully struggled with them is an occupational hazard for mathematicians.

+1, this is probably the best way to sum up the whole issue

This answer might be better with some elaboration about the reasons that this happens so often.

Yes. What's obvious after a solution is presented is seldom obvious before. But this is more of a general issue to everyone. I think the OP may have doubts about his/her approach to solving certain problems or may be using the same approach to all sorts of questions.

Partial response.
I don’t think you can get a comprehensive answer from strangers who don’t personally know you and your circumstances. That said, as a fellow student, I must say that you cannot confuse an easy problem with one that has a short solution. We are used to doing this from school mathematics, but in higher mathematics there tend to be so many rabbit holes of thought you can wander down that arriving at the correct answer is genuinely difficult no matter how brief the final write-up is.
Proofs and solutions exposed in textbooks are deliberately abbreviated and very rarely explore the original motivation to think along those lines. Authors can be terse and the hidden details between the lines may be more difficult than they first appear. It can also depend a lot on your training how easy a problem is and how short you can make your solution look. For example, if you know topology, a lot of introductory real analysis is made much simpler: you can impress your fellow students with efficient proofs, but that doesn’t make a comment about anybody’s intelligence. If you know category theory, many aspects of abstract algebra (and more advanced topology) are clarified: you can give one line proofs that somebody not trained in the theory might take a whole page to prove, or more.
Similarly, it’s very hard to know without the right experience whether or not the track you’re on is along the right lines. It may be that the solution requires no difficult computation, but it may be that it does. Assessing the ‘hardness’ of a result is something even the best mathematicians get wrong (Hilbert famously claimed the transcendence of $2^\sqrt{2}$ a harder problem than Fermat’s last theorem, which is waaay off the mark).
So, regardless of your “intelligence” (very hard and perhaps uninteresting to define!), I urge you not to think short problems are easy, or easy-looking answers beget easy problems. 45 minutes is a perfectly reasonable amount of time to spend on that problem, depending on how much experience you have.

A well put answer. As well, in math we can be thinking simultaneously about different approaches to the one we're pursuing. So it's not like experimental work where we have a clear record of our thought pattern and can thereafter make our approach more efficient for similar problems.

It's easier to re-hike a trail after you already have hiked it before.
As you solve and do more problems, you'll start developing a recognition for certain patterns and behaviors that appear in various topics/ideas, and will you'll eventually will start to be able to solve them faster and faster. It's a phenomenon every intro mathematician experiences, and the fact that you're experiencing it means you're doing okay.
Lastly, don't underestimate smaller problems like you're mentioning. It isn't the amount of words that makes a problem difficult, it's the amount of required logic/background needed to solve them they carry. Sometimes, the most challenging problems are the ones we could fully write down, with room, on a sticky note.

As a freshman you should test yourself a bit.
But you should not be demoralized by occasions when you don't get a particular problem quite as fast as you think you "should" - or when others in the class do.
At your age you are still getting to know who you are, how your mind works, how to approach problems in general and specific kinds of problems.
The important thing is you found a proof.
Now run back over the blind alleys your pursued before the insight arrived (or however you tripped over it) and ask yourself why this type of proof yields to this approach. Was there a logic in the statement of the question that if pursued would have eliminated some options or suggested others ? Was there a concept involved in the stated problem, a concept whose properties would rationally lead to a line of proof or elimination ?
Now that you have found one proof don't neglect to look for alternate proof approaches that might be more congenial to your own mind's way of thinking. This will be useful in the years ahead.
Understanding is more important than speed.

Most achievers tend to compare themselves with those who're better at the given task and vice-versa. But sometimes it has negative consequences like demoralization and at least that's when we should stop comparing.
Especially in geometry I've struggled a lot and many at times have seen what took me 15 steps could be done in 5. My nice teacher told me to remember it so as not to spend as much time on it if I come across something similar and understand properly why and how it works.
Basically learning matters and increasing your inventory. Also, I can't tell you enough how many times I've got lucky by those lengthy methods I employed as when teachers twisted the problem I could see that now this would work (and sometimes - this won't - which is almost equally helpful).
Unless we're Nikola Tesla or Mike Ross (whoever you know better), I think that solving problems mentally is an exercise in itself. Doing lengthy stuff and that too along the road we've not travelled before is sure to take a lot of toll and consequently become prone to errors. It's okay to write something in between (will help in tracing error(s) too though striving still should be for as much mentally as possible).
"is my intelligence just not high enough?" - you never thought this, I never read this.
Other answers cover everything rest and well.

Do you have a strategy for solving problems other than just "tedious effort"? There are lots of approaches you can take, to help you solve a problem like this. For example, draw a diagram, try to find a counterexample, solve an easier problem to try to get insights, break the problem into steps, work backwards, and so on. It takes a while to learn to use these, but you can learn them. A famous mathematician called George Polya wrote a book called How to Solve It which I've heard lots of praise for, which describes strategies like these, but there are lots of other books out there (plus, I imagine, YouTube videos, websites etc.). Or feel free to ask follow-up questions about how you would do any one or combination of those for specific problems here.
To your second question, proofs like this shouldn't be taxing your working memory anywhere near your limit. You should be able to write down a procedure for what you're trying to do, then follow it. You might do this by writing down your initial idea the direction you're going to go down, then re-writing it over and over, adding more detail in each step.
